# Saving more data to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I know it is best way to use JSON but it is too complex for me to understand. Thus, may i ask is there any other ways to make sure that my data does not overwrite in local storage. Example using for loop or using another key name. Please help me by giving my examples as i am very new to HTML/JavaScript.

```
function saveToLS(){

    var Name = document.getElementById("rName");
    var namesaved = Name.value;
    localStorage.setItem("Name",namesaved);


    var Comment = document.getElementById("rComment");
    var commentsaved = Comment.value;
    localStorage.setItem("Comment",commentsaved);   


}
```

Comment: many people prefer using JSON because, JSON object inbuilt have some powerful methods so that we can retrieve data easily. If you don't want to use JSON, you should add all the keys manually as above one by one and retrieve one by one.

Comment: use an identificator (unique key), or namespacing so your data will not be overridden

Comment: But how do i do it? i tried manually having different keys for them. However when stored in my local storage, the value is all the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to store multiples of these? You should store them in an array or object (for example adding a timestamp id field) and store that array in LS.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is using JSON. JSON is not very complex. It's just a string which is a result of stringification of a language construct like an array or object.

What you need is an array: `[]`, stringified version of it: `"[]"`. So you need to push an element into the array. How? Convert the stored JSON string into an array by parsing it, and then push an element and stringify the new array. Here is an example:

```
var names = localStorage.getItem("Name");
names = names ? JSON.parse(names) : [];
names.push('newName');

localStorage.setItem("Name", JSON.stringify(names));
```

Also don't use 2 keys for storing 2 datum that belongs to one item. It will be hard to maintain. Use an object, an array of objects:

```
comments.push({
  author: 'name of the author',
  comment: 'here goes the comment body...'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Yeah..Me Also new In this Part... but I hope to you help full this code please try It..

var key = 0;

for(key;key<10;key++){
  localStorage.setItem(key, localStorage.getItem(key) + "Datas");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveToLS(){

var Name = document.getElementById("rName");
var namesaved = Name.value;
if(localStorage.setItem("Name").length){   //the data already exists
     // Do whatever if the data already Exists......
}else{
    localStorage.setItem("Name",namesaved);
}


var Comment = document.getElementById("rComment");
var commentsaved = Comment.value;


if(localStorage.setItem("Comment").length){ //the data already exists
     // Do whatever if the data already Exists......
}else{
    localStorage.setItem("Comment",commentsaved);
}
```

}

check using localStorage.getItem(), if the data already exists and if its true don't write the data again or for that matter do whatever you want like save the data with another key

```
if(localStorage.setItem("Name").length){   //the data already exists
 localStorage.setItem("SomethingElse...",namesaved); //something else
}else{
   localStorage.setItem("Name",namesaved); 
}
```

Comment: for the part //Do whatever if the data already exist. I don't quite understand what to do

Comment: I mean what do you want to do if some data already exists do you want to over write it, keep the old one or store both the old data and the new data ?

Comment: I want to store both the old and the new data. Overwriting is the issue that i does not want to happen as i am creating a blog. And i have a specific place for it to be printed